# How to not display zero value and shift it in FastReport

Tags: delphi, reporting, fastreport

I have one question in FastReport. I need to make a report in which I see only non zero value. For example I have masterdata which fill data from sql query. On masterdata I put 3 description and value fields. Its look like this:

```
[DATA."DESC1"] DESCRIPTION1 [DATA."VALUE1"] 100
[DATA."DESC2"] DESCRIPTION2 [DATA."VALUE2"] 0
[DATA."DESC3"] DESCRIPTION3 [DATA."VALUE3"] 50
```

and I want to see on report

```
DESCRIPTION1 100
DESCRIPTION3 50
```

but now I see view like this

```
DESCRIPTION1 100

DESCRIPTION3 50
```

I do not want to see blank position, I need to shift third position on second position because the second value is null. Of course in my SQL query there is much more fields with value. I try to find some loop that solve my problem but I didn`t found. I try to use properties Visible or ShiftMode but it not help for this. Mayby someone knows how to solve this problem in FastReport. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an additional option, you may always use the `OnBeforePrint` event (in this case for the `MasterData` band) and organize your logic:

Example, when the `DATA."VALUE2"` is 0:

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
   top: Extended;                                     
begin
   top := 0;                           
   // TfrxMemoView 1                                                    
   Memo1.SetBounds(Memo1.Left, top, Memo1.Width, Memo1.Height);
   top := top + Memo1.Height;
   // TfrxMemoView 2                                                       
   if (<DATA."VALUE2"> = 0) then begin                                      
      Memo2.Visible := False;                                                      
      end
   else begin
      Memo2.Visible := True;                                                      
      Memo2.SetBounds(Memo2.Left, top, Memo2.Width, Memo2.Height);
      top := top + Memo2.Height;
   end;
   // TfrxMemoView 3                                                       
   Memo3.SetBounds(Memo3.Left, top, Memo3.Width, Memo3.Height);
   top := top + Memo3.Height;
end;
```

Example, when the `DATA."VALUE1"` is 0:

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
   top: Extended;                                     
begin
   top := 0;                           
   // TfrxMemoView 1                                                    
   if (<DATA."VALUE1"> = 0) then begin                                      
      Memo1.Visible := False;                                                      
      end
   else begin
      Memo1.Visible := True;                                                      
      Memo1.SetBounds(Memo1.Left, top, Memo1.Width, Memo1.Height);
      top := top + Memo1.Height;
   end;
   // TfrxMemoView 2                                                       
   Memo2.SetBounds(Memo2.Left, top, Memo2.Width, Memo2.Height);
   top := top + Memo2.Height;
   // TfrxMemoView 3                                                       
   Memo3.SetBounds(Memo3.Left, top, Memo3.Width, Memo3.Height);
   top := top + Memo3.Height;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try to impelement this solution in my case but I think that it could be good solution.

Comment: Hi, your solution should be ok. Could you tell me how to change this code when first record will be 0 and I need to shift second record on the position where was first?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for the MasterData band, make sure Stretchable is set to True and Stretch Mode is set to Actual Size.

Answer (score 0):

It would be trivial if your query returns those values as multiple rows instead of multiple columns.

Your current query must be something like :

```
select 'Name' as Desc1, Name as Value1, 'Surname' as Desc2, Surname as Value2, 'Address' as Desc3, Address as Value3, ....
from MyTable
where Id = X
```

You can change it to :

```
select 'Name' as Desc, Name as Value
from MyTable
where Id = X
union
select 'Surname' as Desc, Surname as Value
from MyTable
where Id = X
union
select 'Address' as Desc, Address as Value
from MyTable
where Id = X
...
```

So now to hide the empty values on FastReports is as easy as filtering them on your dataset before executing the report.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that It could be good solution but I have to do this data like a multiple columns not rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also place 3 different MasterData bands (or more), all of them linked to DATA. So you can insert each Memo in their own MasterData, and use OnBeforePrint to hide that MasterData when its particular content is empty.